# Android Java cannot call ASyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am new to android and java programming but I have been given a task to finish an app that a contractor started.  I looked up and found how to call an ASync task and wait for it to finish but I can't get it to work.  In fact, it won't even compile.  I copied it right from one of the answers in [How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

The errors I get are below. They come in MyCalling class. I appended ***** to the end of the line that has the error

error:

```
   processFinish(String) in <anonymous 
   com.zoeller.z_controlmobile.MyCallingClass$2> cannot implement 
   processFinish(String) in AsyncResponse
   attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

and

```
   error: incompatible types: AsyncTask<String,String,String> cannot be 
   converted to MyASyncClass
```

My code is below

```
public class MyCallingClass extends ActivityBase {
    private String _result = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        callingMethod();
    }

    protected void callingMethod() {
        MyASyncClass whatever = new MyASyncClass(new MyASyncClass.AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            void processFinish(String output) { *****
                _result = output;
            }
        }).execute();
    }

    // More work done here
}

public class MyASyncClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
    }

    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    public DeviceConnect(AsyncResponse delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override    
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Does the work
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        delegate.processFinish(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the bold just puts ** around it

Comment: Do you pass any parameters to asynctask?

Comment: add `public` in front of `void processFinish`

Comment: Yes, I pass a single string.

Comment: That works.  I had tried it but I didn't realize I needed to cast it.  Thank you.  If you post it as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: It compiles now but the caller it still continues without the ASync task completing.

Comment: I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyCallingClass extends ActivityBase {
private String _result = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    callingMethod();
}

private void callingMethod() {
    MyASyncClass whatever = new MyASyncClass(output -> _result = output);
    whatever.execute();
}
}

class MyASyncClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);
}

private AsyncResponse delegate = null;

MyASyncClass(AsyncResponse delegate){
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Does the work

    return "";
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(String result) {
    delegate.processFinish(result);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're declaring an interface with the following code:

```
public class MyASyncClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
    }

     ...
}
```

the **access modifier** of `void processFinish(String output)` is implicitly assigned to `public`. So, what you're really get is:

```
public class MyASyncClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    public interface AsyncResponse {
        public void processFinish(String output);
    }

    ...
}
```

When you're constructing an object from the interface, you need to override both the method and the access modifier. Something like this:

```
MyASyncClass.AsyncResponse response = new MyASyncClass.AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String output) {
           // do something with the output.
        }
    };
```